# Creating a Stack Generic ArrayList useing a interface

Tags: java, arraylist, interface, stack

This is a practice question on generics and implementing a Stack(LIFO) not to be used in real life it is for educational purpose.

All interfaces methods can not take different parameters and must be implemented the way shown.

**Interface Stack**

```
import java.util.Iterator;
interface Stack<E>{
    public boolean push(E x);
    public boolean pop();
    public E top();
    public boolean empty();
    public boolean full();
    public Iterator<E> iterator();
}
```

I have no Idea what to do with the `iterator` method or why I would need it here as none of my methods are using it?

I have completed all other methods in the code below

**MyStack**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class MyStack<E> implements Stack<E>,Iterable<E> {

    //Creating a ArrayList which is bound using a int
    //in the constructor and size keeps track of the 
    //amount of elements in the ArrayLIst
    private int size;
    private ArrayList<E> stack;

    public MyStack(int size) {
        stack = new ArrayList<E>(size);
        size = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean push(E x) {
        //Check to make sure the size of the bounded Arraylist
        //has not been exceeded, if not add element 
        if(size == stack.size()) {
            stack.add(x);
            size++;
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    @Override

    public boolean pop() {
        //If the list is not empty remove the last element 
        if(this.empty()) {
            System.out.println("No elements to remove");
            return false;
        }

        stack.remove(stack.size()-1);
        size--;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public E top() {
        //If the stack is not empty return the top element without removing it
        if (empty()) {
            return null;
        }       
        else
            return stack.get(stack.size()-1);       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean empty() {

        return stack.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean full() {

        //If size is equal to the size of the stack
        //it is deemed full
        if(size == stack.size()) {
            System.out.println("The stack is full");
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyStack [size=" + size + ", stack=" + stack + "]";
    }

}
```

**Test Code**

```
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(4);
    stack.push(5);
    stack.push(7);

    System.out.println(stack.toString());

    System.out.println(stack.top());
    stack.pop();
    stack.empty();

    System.out.println(stack.toString());
```

All the methods seem to work correctly

`MyStack [size=4, stack=[2, 4, 5, 7]]
7
MyStack [size=4, stack=[2, 4, 5]]`

The only other confusion I have is in my book it shows a diagram of adding to the head where my Arraylist adds to the tail but treats the tail like it was the head is this ok?

It is a bit confusing as they are also talking about a `LinkedList` in this chapter which is what this daigram looks to represent to me rather than an `ArrayList`.

[image]

**Method Used In Book**

```
@Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
          ArrayList<E> tmp = new ArrayList<>();

            int ind = stack.size();
            while(ind > 0){
              tmp.add(stack.get(ind-1));
                ind--;
            }
            System.out.println(tmp.toString());
            return tmp.iterator();
    }
```

Comment: The `iterator()` method should return an object that can iterate over the whole stack. In your case, it points to a stack object and it can test if there is an object after it(`hasNext()`) and return the currect object and set it's pointer to the next object (`next()`)

Comment: I know the methods but I still can not see why I would need it here in the book the method used is now in the question. This returns an object with the List reversed but it does not use any of the iterator methods and I can only see this being used for visual representation is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

As dan1st already mentioned in the comments an Iterator is used to traverse/iterate over the whole stack and provide some functions to interact with the elements of the stack.

Have a look at the docs of the [Iterator interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

In general, the methods an interface - your stack - provides do not necessarly have to be used in your own implementation but provide the user some operations to interact with your implementation.

> The only other confusion I have is in my book it shows a diagram of adding to the head where my Arraylist adds to the tail but treats the tail like it was the head is this ok?

If the requirement is to add new elements to the head go for it. It changes the order of the elements of the stack.
This is a nice hint how to use the `iterate()` implementation in your book.

Comment: By the way, if the OP doesn't want to implement `iterator()`, he should throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` instead of leaving it blank...